# Viewpager scroll causes SIGSEGV

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am developing an "Gallery-like" feature on my app and I use Viewpager to do this. It works all fine on almost all phone.

But, when i run it on XiaoMi5, it cause SIGSEGV. below is the log info.

```
  07-15 14:36:59.451 5709-6037/com.abc E/OpenGLRenderer:  resultIndex is -1, the polygon must be invalid!
  07-15 14:36:59.452 5709-6037/com.abc A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x592 in tid 6037 (hwuiTask1)
  07-15 14:36:59.528 730-730/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
  07-15 14:36:59.528 730-730/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint:  'Xiaomi/gemini/gemini:6.0/MRA58K/V7.3.4.0.MAACNDD:user/release-keys'
  07-15 14:36:59.529 730-730/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
  07-15 14:36:59.529 730-730/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
  07-15 14:36:59.530 730-730/? A/DEBUG: pid: 5709, tid: 6037, name: hwuiTask1  >>> com.abc <<<
  07-15 14:36:59.530 730-730/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x592
  07-15 14:36:59.573 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     r0 000000b2  r1 000000b3  r2 00000002  r3 000000b2
  07-15 14:36:59.573 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     r4 000000b3  r5 000000b1  r6 00000016  r7 d818ff38
  07-15 14:36:59.573 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     r8 d8190270  r9 000000af  sl d818f5f8  fp 00000023
  07-15 14:36:59.573 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     ip 00000589  sp 00000000  lr f5e9a55b  pc f5e9a3c2  cpsr 000f0030
 07-15 14:36:59.580 730-730/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
 07-15 14:36:59.581 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000563c2  /system/lib/libhwui.so
 07-15 14:36:59.581 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00057441  /system/lib/libhwui.so
 07-15 14:36:59.581 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00051ff1  /system/lib/libhwui.so
 07-15 14:36:59.581 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00058481  /system/lib/libhwui.so
 07-15 14:36:59.581 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0001f1f1  /system/lib/libhwui.so
 07-15 14:36:59.581 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00010115  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+112)
 07-15 14:36:59.581 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0005e22b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+70)
 07-15 14:36:59.581 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0003f9e3  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
 07-15 14:36:59.581 730-730/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00019fe5  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
 07-15 14:37:00.449 730-730/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_07
 07-15 14:37:00.449 730-730/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
 07-15 14:37:00.472 3290-4249/? E/octvm_klo: read: Unexpected EOF!
```

can anyone helps me for this, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fatal signal 11 (**SIGSEGV**) this can appear due to some memmory management issue at native level. Setting the layer type to **View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE** will disable the hardware acceleration, you can find more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html). Disabling can **decrease the performance** but depending on what are you loading into the viewpager it may or may not be visible.

However the side effect of disabling the hardware accelaration is that some memory management is not done at **native level** so less chance for something to go wrong there.

But doing this does not solve the problem it is just avoiding it. The problem can be an **OOM** case, so I recommend that you analyse your memory usage using tools like Memory analyzer (*Android Studio> Android Monitor tab> Monitors> Memory*). Other possible cause can be if you are using some special **native library** that do crazy stuff native.